# How do I tell if a linq to sql object is new, modified or unchanged?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a single linq to sql class.  I would like to detect if it is new (meaning an insert will be done) or if there are any pending changes (update will be done).  I realize that I can do this by using a `partial` class and hooking into the on change events for each property.  However that is a lot of maintenance for a class that is constantly changing.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check through the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298245(v=VS.100).aspx) class.

First, check the [`ObjectTrackingEnabled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled(v=VS.100).aspx) on the `DataContext`.  If it returns false, then the object is not being tracked by the context.

Then, call the [`GetChangeSet` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534224(v=VS.100).aspx) on the `DataContext`.  From there, compare the references exposed by the [`Deletes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.deletes(v=VS.100).aspx), [`Updates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.updates(v=VS.100).aspx), and [`Inserts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeset.inserts(v=VS.100).aspx) properties against your object.

If the reference is found in any of those lists, then your object is being tracked by that list and you can proceed from there.

Comment: So the only way to do it is from the DataContext then?  I was hoping to just do it from the object instance alone.

Comment: @Jason Webb: If you don't have a DataContext then it's irrelevant, you can't do an insert, update, or delete without one, and the state of the object is detached.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the id of the object is 0.

```
if someId = 0
  Insert();
else
  Update();
```

Simples

Comment: Research DeferredLoading and google for Detach() method - it's something you'll have to implement, but it'll save you some trouble with inserting through LINQ.